# Heroku Production: config.autoload_paths doesnt seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production

I have a Rails application that works just fine in development. It accesses a class I have in my `/lib` folder due to the

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

line in my **application.rb** config file. However, when I run the application in production on Heroku, I get an `Uninitialized Constant` error.

For example running `rails c` locally:

```
>rails c
001> OrderPdf
 => OrderPdf
002>
```

but on production:

```
>heroku run rails c
001> OrderPdf
NameError: uninitialized constant OrderPdf
(stack trace)
002>
```

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 3):

its because on prod you probably have this line in your config `config.eager_load = true`
, which loads all of your classes once before hand.

To fix this, everything that you add to the autoload_path, add to the eager_load path as well

`config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`